# boost::details::pool::pthread_mutex and boost::details::pool::null_mutex

Tags: c++, boost, pthreads, mutex

What is the differance between `boost::details::pool::pthread_mutex` and `boost::details::pool::null_mutex`.

I see that in latest boost version - 1.42, the class  `boost::details::pool::pthread_mutex` was deleted. What should I use instead?

Comment: I believe the latest released version of Boost is 1.49. Boost 1.42 is a couple years old...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::details::pool::null_mutex` is a mutex that does nothing (a lock always succeeds immediately).  It's appropriate when you're not using threads.  The Boost pool library selects what kind of mutex it will use to synchronize access to critical sections with a typedef for the mutex type based on the following snippet from `boost\pool\detail\mutex.hpp`:

```
#if !defined(BOOST_HAS_THREADS) || defined(BOOST_NO_MT) || defined(BOOST_POOL_NO_MT)
  typedef null_mutex default_mutex;
#else
  typedef boost::mutex default_mutex;
#endif
```

In other words, if the configuration says that no threading is involved (either for Boost as a whole, or for the pool library in particular), then the `null_mutex` will be used (which is basically a nop).

If threading is to be supported, then the `boost::mutex` type will be used, which comes from the Boost thread library (and will be a pthread-based mutex if your system uses pthreads).

Comment: so boost:detail::poolLpthread_mutex was moved to boost:thread::mutex?

Comment: I don't know how it was set up before - just that now the mutex is by default a typedef for boost::mutex if boost is configured for threading.  Maybe before boost::pool had it's own little custom thread support and they decided to leverage the boost::thread library at some point (I'm just guessing - I only have 1.49 installed at the moment).